# Shaped background

Tags: css, background-image, transparency, css-shapes

I would like to make some background shapes on my website ...

[this is the look that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBJIm.jpg)

I have tried using the method with rotated/skewed rectangles, it works perfect just when I have only one color on the section below (because I can use the same color for the shapes). If I want to use a texture like in the image attached I will end up having [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0kne7rs78pbry4/test000.jpg?dl=0) depending on what method I use. I have also tried using a svg for making the shapes, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. I'm wondering if there is a clever way to do this. I realize maybe I'm not as clear as a should be, but thank you for finding time to read this.

Comment: This a two white block with `transform: skewY()` and `position: absolute`

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to experiment with SVGs and masks, depending upon how complicated your shapes are going to be. You can find some great guidance here: https://www.sitepoint.com/masking-in-the-browser-with-css-and-svg/.

Illustrator can be saved as an SVG, but if you're using Sketch it's even easier! You'll notice the code outputs individual coordinates.

You can see a decent demo here: http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Comment: You can also cheat and use white triangle .png files overlaid, absolutely positioned to the bottom right to create the funky edging. It's a much simpler solution, though obviously will add weight to your body.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the ideas and for your time. I'll let you know if masks worked for me. The white png trick isn't working, because I don't need white triangles. (I have tried to explain better in my question)

Answer (score 0):

This a concept. Try self to work project.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 66.6666667%, rgba(255, 255, 0, .6) 66.6666667%), url(http://beerhold.it/1200/600);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 100%), url(http://beerhold.it/1400/700);
  }

.topleft,
.topright,
.bottomleft,
.bottomright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  left: 0;
  top: 40%;
  width: 66.66666667%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0, transparent 50%, #fff 50%, #fff);
  transform: skewY(7deg);
}
.topright {
  left: 66.66666667%;
  width: 33.33333334%;
  top: 42.3%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0, transparent 50%, #fff 50%, #fff);
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}

.bottomleft {
  left: 0;
  top: -94%;
  width: 33.33333334%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0, transparent 50%, #fff 50%, #fff );
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.bottomright {
  left: 33.33333334%;
  width: 66.66666667%;
  top: -92%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0, transparent 50%, #fff 50%, #fff);
  transform: skewY(7deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topleft"></div>
  <div class="topright"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topleft"></div>
  <div class="topright"></div>
  <div class="bottomleft"></div>
  <div class="bottomright"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it. It's an interesting solution, a little different from what I did. However, maybe I missing something, but my initial problem was that I need to use a texture on the sections below the main image which has the shapes. And because of that those white shapes must be transparent or i don't know maybe it's a better solution that i don't see...I attached a link, not sure if you understand what I'm trying to say here. Is there a way to do that?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zwyn4dwvbex37h/test03.jpg?dl=0

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: im upded my answer.

Comment: not sure if you finished, but here is what I say it must be transparent. Thank you again!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fz1d3d833oh5gz/test04.jpg?dl=0